# Pygame Buttons, First button working, second button not working

Tags: python, button, pygame

I have recently been working on a game using python and pygame and have started on buttons for various things. An issue that I have been running into is when I create a button class and create two objects of that class for each button, both of them will turn darker when hovered over by the mouse as expected, but only the first one to process will detect when the player clicks it. I started a new python file with the same button class and mostly the same code and it still has the same issue. I have tried processing the buttons separately and changing various other things but the only way I can get the second button to work is by processing it first, but then the first button won't work. Here is that simplified code.

```py
import pygame

class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, hover_color, click_func):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.color = color
        self.hover_color = hover_color
        self.display_color = self.color
        self.click_func = click_func

    def process(self):
        events = pygame.event.get()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.display_color = self.hover_color
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.click_func()

        else:
            self.display_color = self.color

def press_func1():
    print('press func 1')

def press_func2():
    print('press func 2')


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

buttons = [
    Button(200, 100, 100, 50, (255, 0, 0), (150, 0, 0), press_func1),
    Button(200, 300, 100, 50, (0, 255, 0), (0, 150, 0), press_func2)
]
    
running = True
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    fps.tick(60)
        
    WIN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    [button.process() for button in buttons]
    [pygame.draw.rect(WIN, button.display_color, button.rect) for button in buttons]
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

If you know what the problem is, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the events and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called multiple times per frame, the events are only retuned once, but never all calls will return all all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the list of events once per frame and pass the list of events to `Button.process`:

```py
import pygame

class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, hover_color, click_func):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.color = color
        self.hover_color = hover_color
        self.display_color = self.color
        self.click_func = click_func

    def process(self, events):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.display_color = self.hover_color
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.click_func()

        else:
            self.display_color = self.color

def press_func1():
    print('press func 1')

def press_func2():
    print('press func 2')


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

buttons = [
    Button(200, 100, 100, 50, (255, 0, 0), (150, 0, 0), press_func1),
    Button(200, 300, 100, 50, (0, 255, 0), (0, 150, 0), press_func2)
]
    
running = True
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    fps.tick(60)
        
    WIN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    events = pygame.event.get()
    [button.process(events) for button in buttons]
    [pygame.draw.rect(WIN, button.display_color, button.rect) for button in buttons]
        
    pygame.display.update()
```