# Pygame buttons clicks and if statments

Tags: python, if-statement, button, mouseevent

I've just started again after a while and having some issues and a little lost.

Have been trying to make menus in pygame using images as buttons. Fuigured most of it out after looking at others but think I'm making a silly mistake and can't figure it out - chopped & changed alot of lines.The first button works and sends you to the correct menu but none of the others register.

Most guides use draw to create buttons, so haven't been helpful.

[Similar but uses draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74503738/pygame-buttons-first-button-working-second-button-not-working)

Have tried moving my IF \ ELIF \ ELSE statements around but get errors or nothing works.

Not really a coder, just wanted something to hold our D&D homebrew together - use TKinter before but thought I'd have a go at this.

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
 
pygame.init()
width=900;
height=800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (width, height ) )
pygame.display.set_caption('Chapter 1')
#TownMap = pygame.image.load("Data/images/town.png").convert()
#Button = pygame.image.load("Data/images/buttonsSolo.png").convert_alpha()

def Main_Menu():  

  Back_Drop = pygame.image.load("Data/images/Art/cursewick1.jpg").convert()
  Start_Button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Start.png").convert_alpha() 
  Help_Button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Help.png").convert_alpha() 
  Exit_Button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Exit.png").convert_alpha() 
  screen.blit(Back_Drop, (0,0))
  screen.blit(Start_Button ,  ( 10,10)) # paint to screen
  screen.blit(Help_Button ,  ( 10,110)) # paint to screen
  screen.blit(Exit_Button ,  ( 10,210)) # paint to screen
  pygame.display.flip() # paint screen one time
  
  mixer.init()
  mixer.music.load("Data\Audio\Music\Intro.mp3")
  pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
  mixer.music.play()
  
  
  running = True
  while (running):  
  
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False
          if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
              # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
              x, y = event.pos
              if Start_Button.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                  print('clicked on image')
                  pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                  Town_Map()
              if Help_Button.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                  print('Help')
                  pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                      
                  

  #loop over, quite pygame
  pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.Surface`s don't have a position, so the `get_rect` method returns a `Rect` with the image dimensions and the coordinates `(x=0, y=0)` for all your images.

You have to save the `blit` position in the surface rect so that the origin coordinates of the rect match the global coordinates where the image is displayed on the screen. For example:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
width = 900
height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Chapter 1')


def main_menu():

    back_drop = pygame.image.load("Data/images/Art/cursewick1.jpg").convert()
    back_drop_rect = back_drop.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))

    start_button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Start.png").convert_alpha() 
    start_button_rect = start_button.get_rect(topleft=(10, 10))

    help_button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Help.png").convert_alpha() 
    help_button_rect = help_button.get_rect(topleft=(10, 110))

    exit_button = pygame.image.load("Data/Images/UI/Buttons/Exit.png").convert_alpha() 
    exit_button_rect = exit_button.get_rect(topleft=(10, 210))

    screen.blit(back_drop, back_drop_rect)
    screen.blit(start_button, start_button_rect)
    screen.blit(help_button, help_button_rect)
    screen.blit(exit_button, exit_button_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.mixer.music.load("Data\Audio\Music\Intro.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                if start_button_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    print("Start")
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                elif help_button_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    print('Help')
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                elif exit_button_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    print('Exit')
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    pygame.quit()


main_menu()
```

Comment: Thank you FJSevilla :) Just got back and tried it and everything works. Also thank you explaining & cleaning up my line :) Sorry if this was a silly question but would have never figured this one out and would either have had to rework it without fancy buttons or given up on it.

Comment: Just to say thank you again, really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Been able to get most of the program built now, and it should allow me to give players abit more flavour.